# datepicker mark some tds with date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have next html, generated by datepicker plugin:

```
<tr>
<td class=" " data-year="2013" data-month="6" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a>
</td>
<td class=" " data-year="2013" data-month="6" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay">
<a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a>
</td>
...
```

And what I need is marking, e.g. with red background color some dates which are being selected from database. Can anyone help me please how to select using jQuery e.g. date 23 day 6 month and 2013 year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for something allong these lines:

```
$('td')
    .filter('[data-year="'+yearYouWant+'"]')
    .filter('[data-month="'+monthYouWant+'"]')
    .find('a') // find all Anchors in this filtered result
    .css({border: '1px solid #F00'});
```

I suggest you dont select all td's (such as in my example) but you first start looking in a div or specific table. This will be better performance-wise (the less you select, the less it has to check, right)

You can easily find elements with [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/). Be carefull tho, try to select as few elements as you possibly can with the first selector (in this case the 'td' ) and try to filter with the selectors which remove the most in their action, so you loop trough the least amount of elements posible.

Comment: This is good thing, but I wonder if I also can somehow check the number within <a></a> tags?

Comment: Updated my answer and added some documentation. Im not gonna give you the final answer (it will now color red), you will have to find the value yourself ;)